# oracle stored procedure - printing varchar2 output variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I execute a stored proc as follows:

```
var myOutput varchar2

exec myproc(:myOutput)

print myOutput
```

However, this does not work.

I get an error message saying:

```
Bind Variable "myOutput" is NOT DECLARED
```

When I use a refcurser rather than a varchar2 in other procs, this works. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bark ( woof IN OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
BEGIN
  woof := 'Woof!';
END bark;
```

Then you run:

```
SQL> var myOutput VARCHAR2(10) 
SQL> exec bark(:myOutput);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print myOutput

MYOUTPUT
--------------------------------
Woof!
```

Is this similiar to what you are trying to do?

Comment: that gives me two errors. First an error about myoutput my being declared when executing the proc, and then the same error was getting above.

Comment: sorry i made some assumptions when i was writing an answer. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Is that *exactly* what you're running?  If so, I think the problem is you're not specifying the size of your `myOutput` variable.  You need to do this (adjusting the length as appropriate to your needs):

```
SQL> var myOutput varchar2(40)
```

It's in [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch13.htm#sthref3134).